# Can we send sms using AWS pinpoint without phone number verification

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm using **AWS pinpoint** to send **OTP** via **SMS**.

For this I have created a Pinpoint project.

It is asking to add destination ( verified phone number ).

If I add a destination it is sending OTP for verification. How can I integrate this with real world application.

If I send a request without adding destination phone number in the AWS console to AWS pinpoint using Nodejs it is showing that the Phone number is not found.

Any other approach to do this my. I need to send OTP using **AWS Pinpoint** without adding destination and need to send **OTP** via **SMS** directly using **Node.js** with **AWS SDK**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially when you use AWS pinpoint SMS service, it will be placed in SMS sandbox, a safe environment so that we can test it. When its in the sandbox, SMS can be sent only to verified phone numbers. If you want to send without phone verification, you need to move it out of the sandbox.

You can refer this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-sandbox.html

Comment: How to move AWS pinpoint out of the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Raise a support case with aws support to move from sandbox to production.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424111/11107541